# Unable to access Oracle Cloud MC server despite following Stack/Google port setup advice

Tags: linux, firewall, cloud

Ive been attempting to set up a Bedrock Minecraft server on a free Oracle VM. I have some experience as I have a server running on a Hetzner instance however a few weeks later after scouring the internet including lots of Stackoverflow posts, I am pulling my hair out trying to get port access externally so I can connect.  I have no issue connecting via SSH.

Here is what I have done.

- Fired up a server using Ubuntu 20.04 image
- Configured a VCN using the Wizard ensuring internet connectivity (an internet gateway) is added
- Set up Ingress rules in the default security list for port 19132
- via SSH disabled firewall and verified with `sudo firewall-cmd --state` the result is 'not running'
- via SSA added to the iptable with

`sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 19132 -j ACCEPT`

tested the port by pinging the public ip and port 19132
result: Port Closed

Arrgghh.

There must be something am overlooking or a way of testing why it is blocking.

Please help me Obiwan, am at my wits end.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue with connecting to my instance. This fixed it.

Let’s reset the firewall rules and open the ssh and Minecraft ports:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

sudo iptables -F

sudo iptables-save

sudo ufw default deny incoming

sudo ufw default allow outgoing

sudo ufw allow 22/tcp

sudo ufw allow 19132/udp

sudo ufw allow 19132/tcp

sudo ufw allow 25565/udp

sudo ufw allow 25565/tcp

sudo ufw enable

sudo ufw status
```

Source: https://blog.adamzolo.com/setting-up-a-free-minecraft-server-on-oracle-cloud/